# Finding the parametric equation of two intersecting surfaces

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I was given two equations of surfaces: an ellipsoid
`(x/2)^2+(y/4)^2+(z/5)^2=1` and a plane `z=3`. So I graphed their intersection like this: 
`ContourPlot3D[{(x/2)^2 + (y/4)^2 + (z/5)^2 == 1, z == -3}, {x, -5,  5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -6, 6},  ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0], Opacity[0]}, Mesh -> None,  BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {Black, Thick}}]`
Now I'm wondering how can I find the parametric form of this intersection using only mathematica. I need the parametric form because I want an animation of a point moving along this curve of intersection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- To animation of a point moving along this curve of intersection,we only need to extract the ordered points from the plot.

```
plot = ContourPlot3D[{(x/2)^2 + (y/4)^2 + (z/5)^2 == 1, 
    z == -3}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -6, 6}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0], Opacity[0]}, Mesh -> None, 
   BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {Black, Thick}}];
pts = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, -1] // First;
f = BSplineFunction[pts];
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[f@s, {s, 0, 1}], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], 
    Point@f@Mod[s, 1]}]], {s, -2, 2}]
```

[image]